# Profile-Object Pair Chatter Permissions

Tags: chatter, permissions

Can we deactivate chatter for a specific object **OX** and profile **PY** pair? Or make read-only if that's a thing.

The issue is that profile **PY** must use chatter normally on other objects and object **OX** needs chatter activated for other profile types. So this has to be a profile-object combination permission. Can we get that fine-grained in SF or has anyone figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two workarounds. Both solutions will render the object's feed items read-only. There's no way to completely disable feed items on an object on a per-profile basis.

## Page Layouts

Create a new page layout, remove the Chatter actions, assign to the profile.

## Trigger

Create a new trigger on FeedItem, and you can block the actions.

```
trigger BlockItems on FeedItem (before insert) {
  if(0 < [select count() from profile where id = :userinfo.getprofileid() and name = 'restricted']) {
    for(FeedItem item: Trigger.new) {
      if(item.ParentId.getSobjectType() == SomeObject__c.SobjectType) {
        item.addError('You cannot add a post to to this type of record.');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I'll try to walk myself through it.

**Line 1:** Add trigger to FeedItem (the Chatter object?)
**Line 2:** Find the user's profile record and check if name is 'restricted' _(replace with **PY** right?)_. If so, proceed.
**Line 3:** Loop through triggering feed items (can be more than one?) _(either the chatter box itself or individual chatter posts? No idea how Chatter organizes objects)._
**Line 4:** If feed item parent is of given object type, proceed _(here I use **OX**?)_.
**Line 5:** Call out error. _(error popup and blocks insertion?)_

Comment: @Christos (1) Yes, (2) Yes, change to **PY**, (3) Theoretically. Also see [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input.htm) for related methods/objects, (4) Yes, change to **OX** as appropriate, and (5) Yes, the user will get a popup when they try to post the message.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate the guidance. I haven't started using Apex yet so I had to stare at this for a while. I'll start looking into how to append this code to my org now..